# Corda tutorial's contract test ledget method error

Tags: corda

I'm trying to implement a Contract test on Java as described [there](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-test-dsl.html).

I paste the first test's code in my project and changed `import static net.corda.testing.NodeTestUtils.ledger;` to `import static net.corda.testing.node.NodeTestUtils.ledger;`

```
package com.template;

import org.junit.Test;

import static net.corda.testing.node.NodeTestUtils.ledger;

public class CommercialPaperTest {
    @Test
    public void emptyLedger() {
        ledger(l -> {
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```

And I see that ledger method has an absolutely different signature, so Java says that it cannot resolve method `ledger(<lambda expression>)`. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on that page. The first argument to `ledger` should be a `MockServices` instance.

For example, we might write:

```
public class CommercialPaperTest {
    private static final TestIdentity megaCorp = new TestIdentity(new CordaX500Name("MegaCorp", "London", "GB"));
    private MockServices ledgerServices;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ledgerServices = new MockServices(
                singletonList("net.corda.finance.contracts"),
                megaCorp,
                makeTestIdentityService(megaCorp.getIdentity())
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyLedger() {
        ledger(ledgerServices, l -> {
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```